# How to pass agruments to ServiceFabric Actor/StatefulService?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a ServiceFabric Actor that is responsible for processing turn-by-turn requests sent to it to check whether inventory is available or not.

These requests are sent to a Stateful Service which checks if inventory is available or not, and returns a true/false accordingly (among other things it does).

In order to get this to work right, I need the ability to pass the inventoryId when the Actor is activated (or initialized?) so that it can also initialize/activate the Stateful Service to load up the Inventory quota and related info from the database.

How can I pass the parameters to the Actor and Stateful service in a constructor? I am currently resorting to passing the inventory Id in each call to the actor and always checking if Service is initialized or not. That is becoming redundant as I add more and more methods.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the inventoryId as the [ActorId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.actors.actorid.-ctor) for the [Actor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.actors.actorreference.get?view=azure-dotnet) that manages the lifecycle of the service. (So one Actor instance for every inventoryId.)

The Actor can then be used to initialize the service with the inventoryId as well.

Finally, the Actor can be used to return the information required to create a proxy to call the service (service name and likely partition information).

Comment: Hello, That's exactly what I ended up doing. Because we're a multi-tenant scenario, I did tenantId:inventoryId as the actor Id and split it up inside the constructor to initialize tenantId and inventoryId so I can load up inventory using those 2 params. It feels clumsy, but gets the job done. Was wondering if there was another way but it may not look like.